# Add a Foreign Key to a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have many tables for example EmployeeType, OrderType, AddressType... etc. these tables has only Id and Name, they look the same so I decided to use only 1 table to simplify the schema here you have the tables:

```
Type
------------
Id         int Identity
EntityId   id that represent the table check the table below
TypeId     id of each table, EmployeeType, OrderType, etc.
Name       Name of the type


Entity
------------
EntityId   
Name
```

Here some example:

Entity table:

```
EntityId   Name
1          EmployeeType
2          OrderType
```

Type table:

```
Id    EntityId  TypeId     Name
1     1         1          Employee
2     1         2          Manager
```

Now I have the Employee table, this table has a TypeId, I need to be able to put a FK to Type table when my EntityId is equal to 1 (EmployeeType) is this possible?

Comment: sorry Name is really the description

Comment: This is known as [One True Lookup Table](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html)

Comment: Possible or not, I recommend against this approach. While it may be tempting to have just one table, you will likely regret this decision when you want to keep more information in one of those `Type`s, or when you find yourself confused when looking at your data. Just build separate tables and keep it simple.

Comment: "simplify the schema" is almost always a bad plan, why are you pursuing this goal?? to reduce the number of tables?  This is a common mistake. It almost always leads to problems. It increases the cost of development, debugging, system enhancements, and overall maintainability.

Comment: clear enough thanks guys!

Comment: If you came to some kind of resolution, please post it as an answer and accept it.